# TypeError when Using NumPy and Floats in Python Functions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, trigonometry

I am trying to write a function to plot a sine graph. The function takes three sine arguments: amplitude being A, frequency being B, horizontal shift being C (see below)

```
A sin(B(x-C))
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 201)


def sine(amplitude, frequency, horizontal_shift) -> object:
    si = np.sin(x - sine)
    si = si * frequency
    si = amplitude * si
    return si


test = sine(4, 1, 2)
print(test)

plt.plot(x, test)
plt.show()
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'function'
```

I have tried to

- input ints only
- input numbers as strings
- defining my function as this:

```
def sine(amplitude, frequency, horizontal_shift) -> object
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: What is `x - sine` supposed to be doing?  `sine` is the function that you just defined.  Math isn't defined for functions!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things. Firstly you don't want `si = np.sin(x - sine)`. This is what the traceback is referring to. Secondly, your function even then isn't doing the calculation that you gave at the top. Try:

```py
def sine(x, amplitude, frequency, horizontal_shift):
    si = amplitude * np.sin(frequency * (x - horizontal_shift))
    return si
```

Edit: plot of sample output

```py
plt.plot(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 201), sine(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 201), 2 , 5, 7))
```

[image]